# Diferenças de funções PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Na documentação não deixa muito explicado isso (acho), então, qual seria a diferença de:

Estou usando a variável `$mail` para o exemplo.

```
$mail->Username
```

---

```
$mail->setFrom
```

---

```
$mail->addAddress
```

---

```
$mail->addReplyTo
```

Esse ultimo `addReplyTo` parece que é o e-mail que vai estar como resposta, na hora que clicarmos em "responder" no nosso e-mail (Se não for me corrijam). Os outros alguém pode dar uma explicação?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Username`: é o usuário utilizado para autenticação (e complementando, o `Password`).

`SetFrom`: seria para adicionar um outro e-mail no lugar do que está usando para envio, mas como tudo hoje exige autenticação para saída, então não tem função. A não ser que você use um SMTP sem autenticação, mas é quase certeza que vá para spam.

`AddAddress`: você adiciona mais destinatários (não é em cópia).

`addReplyTo`: como você disse, seria para o "responder", mas se você usa o `AddAddress`, ele responde para todos, pois estarão como integrantes, e não "em cópia".

`Subject`: é o assunto do seu e-mail.

`Body`: o conteúdo do seu e-mail (podendo ser simples texto ou HTML).

`AddEmbeddedImage`: adicionar imagens "embutidas".

`SMTPDebug`: para definir o tipo de debug.

o PHPMailer também já tem um controle em que evita a duplicidade dos destinatários, ele mesmo filtra e seta somente 1 caso você informe mais iguais.

---

Um exemplo completo:

```
// Cria objeto
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$titulo         = 'Teste';
$emailAssunto   = 'Exemplo de assunto';
$conteudo = 'Hello World :D';

$mail->Subject   = $emailAssunto;
$mail->Body      = $conteudo;
$mail->AddReplyTo('a@a.com');
$mail->setFrom('b@b.com', $titulo); // Basicamente para setar o título
$mail -> AddAddress('c@c.com');
$mail -> AddAddress('d@d.com');

// Define parâmetros
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )   
);
$mail->CharSet   = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Host      = $this -> srvNome;
$mail->Port      = $this -> srvPort;
$mail->Username  = $this -> srvEmail;
$mail->Password  = $this -> srvSenha;
//$mail->IsHTML(true);

// Envia o e-mail
if (!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Erro ao enviar e-mail.";  
} else {
    echo "E-mail enviado !";
}
```

Sempre usei sob esse conceito. Caso alguma objeção, favor comente.

Comment: Show RBZ, obrigado! Só mais uma dúvida kk, o Subject seria o título dos e-mails? Vi aqui agora e bateu essa dúvida também.

Comment: Corrigi o subject e adicionei um script completo de exemplo. Assim facilita entender, acredito eu. ;]

Comment: Obrigado, RBZ! Ajudou pra caramba!